# Passing object as argument, for function to evaluate method

Tags: c++, function, object, methods, arguments

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studios.

I'm trying to mimic a process I've used in Java, but am having a hard time.

I'd like to be able to pass the name of an object from a class into a function as its argument. And then have the function evaluate the value of the method within the object passed.

The program is for a simulated old school gum dispensing machine.

Edit #2:

OK, went through and re-edited code. Now I'm getting a huge error message, but its only for one part...

Code:

```
//Vintage Gum Vending Machine (A4)

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

//input select
char input;

 //gum stock


class Gum {
public:
  Gum(string Name, int Stock) {
        Name = name;
        Stock = stock;
  };


  int stock;
  string name;

};


Gum Beemans  ("Beemans",10);        

Gum Dentyne  ("Dentyne", 10);       

Gum Chiclets ("Chiclets", 10); 

Gum Carefree ("Carefree", 10); 



//Main Welcome Menu 
void welcomeMenu();

//coin queue of deposited quarters
float Queue = 0.00;
//coin deposit quarter drop
void dropQuarter();

//Tab pulled function
void pulltab(Gum& gum);

//Money in the Machine
float Vault = 0.00;
//Empty deposit queue into vault
void resetQueue();

//restock machine
void restock();




int main()
{
welcomeMenu();

do 
{ 
    //take menu choice
    cin >> input;

    switch (input)
    {
        case 's' :  cout << "Stock Status:  " <<endl
                         << "1: Beemans: " << Beemans.stock  <<endl
                         << "2: Dentyne: " << Dentyne.stock  <<endl
                         << "3: Chiclets: "<< Chiclets.stock <<endl
                         << "4: Carefree: "<< Carefree.stock <<endl
                         << "There is $" << Vault << " in the machine" <<endl;
            break;

        case 'd' :  cout << "You drop in a quarter \n Clink " <<endl;
                    dropQuarter();
            break;

        case '1' :  cout << "You reach for the 1st tab and" <<endl;
                    pulltab(Beemans);
            break;

        case '2' :  cout << "You reach for the 2nd tab and" <<endl;
                    pulltab(Dentyne);
            break;

        case '3' :  cout << "You reach for the 3rd tab and" <<endl;
                    pulltab(Chiclets);
            break;

        case '4' :  cout << "You reach for the 4th tab and" <<endl;
                    pulltab(Carefree);
            break;

        case 'r' :  cout << "You call the store clerk to restock the machine " <<endl;
            break;

        case 'q' :  cout << "quiting program " <<endl;
            break;

        default  :  cout << "Please select a choice from the menu" <<endl;
                    welcomeMenu();
                    cout << "Please select a choice from the menu" <<endl;

            break;
    }
} while (input != 'q');






return 0;
};


void welcomeMenu() 
{
cout << "s - view stock status " <<endl;
cout << "d - drop in a quarter " <<endl;
cout << "1 - pull 1st tab " <<endl;
cout << "2 - pull 2nd tab " <<endl;
cout << "3 - pull 3rd tab " <<endl;
cout << "4 - pull 4th tab " <<endl;
cout << "r - restock the machine " <<endl;
cout << "q - quit " <<endl;
cout << "(make your selection then press enter)"<<endl;

};

void dropQuarter(){
Queue += 0.25;
};

void pulltab(Gum& gum){



if(gum.stock >=1 && Queue>=0.75){
    cout<< "pull the tab out." << endl
        << "The machine dispenses a pack of " << gum.name << "." <<endl
        << "After taking the pack of gum, you push the tab back in." <<endl;
    gum.stock -= 1; 
    resetQueue();
}
else if(gum.stock==0 && Queue>=0.75){
    cout<< "pull the tab out." <<endl
        << "But no " << gum.name << "comes out of the slot..." <<endl
        << "(Hint: did you check to see if the gum was in stock before depositing your money in this simulated 1960s gum machine?)" <<endl;
        resetQueue();
}else if(Queue<0.75) {
    cout << "pull on the tab, but it doesn\'t budge..."<<endl
         << "(Hint: Gum costs 75 ¢ ... have you dropped in at least 3 quarters?)" <<endl;
}

};

void resetQueue(){
Vault += Queue;
Queue = 0.00;
};
```

Errors (sorry its so big):

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: Assignment 4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Assignment 4.cpp
1>c:\users\mark\desktop\academic\cs\assignment4\assignment4\assignment 4.cpp(146): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(695): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(742): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(780): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>           ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(827): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
1>          with
1>           [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(953): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const signed char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(960): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(967): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(974): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(984): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::string>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,const _Ty &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(1101): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>           ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(201): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(207): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(214): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(221): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::_Bool)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(241): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(short)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(275): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned short)'
1>          with
1>            [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>               _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(295): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(320): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>               _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(340): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(360): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(381): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(__int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(401): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned __int64)'
 1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(422): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(float)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(442): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio  11.0\vc\include\ostream(462): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>           ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(482): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(const void *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>                _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(502): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>, std::string)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>c:\users\mark\desktop\academic\cs\assignment4\assignment4\assignment 4.cpp(153): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(695): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>           [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(742): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(780): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(827): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(953): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const signed char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(960): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char)'
 1>          with
 1>          [
 1>              _Elem=char,
 1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(967): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(974): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(984): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::string>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,const _Ty &)'
 1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(1101): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
 1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
 1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(201): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(207): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(214): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(221): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::_Bool)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(241): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(short)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(275): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned short)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(295): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(320): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(340): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(360): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(381): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(__int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(401): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned __int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(422): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(float)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(442): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(462): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(482): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(const void *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(502): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>, std::string)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You prototyped `void pulltab();` but then declare it to take `Gum`.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What are they? Please post them.

Comment: First, pulltab takes a pointer to the object and you are calling it inconsistently.  Beemans and the other Gum pointers should be passed to the function without the * or &.  Call it like this, pulltab(Beemans);

Comment: If you saw my answer, I've already mentioned these errors and how to correct them. I suggest you to take a look again.

Answer (score 0):

First, pulltab takes a pointer to the object and you are calling it inconsistently. Beemans and the other Gum pointers should be passed to the function without the * or &. Call it like this, You also have a memory leak.  In C++ you need to delete objects that you create with new.  I would not bother with the new keyword if I were you.  Just do this,

Now if you take my advice, the '->' should be changed to '.' for invoking functions.

```
// Tab pulled function - fixed prototype to use pass by reference
// Do the same in the implementation
void pulltab(Gum& theGum);

// create objects like this.  You can leave it global or do it in the body of main
Gum Beemans("Beemans",10);

// call it like this
pulltab(Beemans); 

// Invoke functions and access attributes like this
if(gum.stock >= 1 && Queue >= 0.75){ // body of block }
```

That's the basics.  From Java to C++ dealing with pointers will seem strange at first so avoid it as much as possible.  Use references, smart pointers, and containers as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should get this error :

> error: too many arguments to function ‘void pulltab()’

You need to declare your prototype like this:

```
//Tab pulled function
void pulltab(Gum *gum);
```

Now, you should have this error :

> error: cannot convert ‘Gum’ to ‘Gum*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void pulltab(Gum*)’

Since you declare a pointer to `Gum` like this : `Gum *Beemans = new Gum("Beemans",10);`, you'll need to pass the argument like this : `pulltab(Beemans);`. Do the same thing for the other calls (without the `&`).

After that, you'll get the following error :

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream’ and ‘’)
>   << "The machine dispenses a pack of " << gum->getName << "." << endl

You forgot the parenthesis. You should call your class member function like this : `gum->getName()`

This should have helped you I hope.